# Filling a form dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to generate a row for each item in my list. The way i'm currently trying to achieve this is with the following:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>People</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
{ this.renderEvents() }
```

---

```
renderEvents() {
    const events = this.state.data;
    console.log(events);

    return (
      <tbody>
        { events.forEach((event) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{event.title}</td>
              <td>{event.startDate}</td>
              <td>{event.userList.length}</td>
              <td><Badge color="success">Coming</Badge></td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    );
}
```

The problem i'm currently facing is that my console.log(events) line gets executed twice and the table stays empty.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return a new array. Try [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead!

```js
return (
  <tbody>
    { events.map((event) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{event.title}</td>
          <td>{event.startDate}</td>
          <td>{event.userList.length}</td>
          <td><Badge color="success">Coming</Badge></td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to do this**

```
render(){
  const data = events.map(
    event => {
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{event.title}</td>
          <td>{event.startDate}</td>
          <td>{event.userList.length}</td>
          <td><Badge color="success">Coming</Badge></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    })

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More React idiomatic solution would be to use a React Component instead of calling function that returns jsx. Component is created once and mounted once, instead, function will each time return a new component (meaning the memory link will change) that will cause React reconciliation mechanism to each time mount and unmount a Component. That is not good for React performance.

I would recommend structuring your code in a next manner:

```
class EventViewer extends React.Component {
     // keep logic of fetching events here and saving them (to state for example)

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <EventVieverHeader />
                <EventVieverBody events={this.state.events}/>
            </table>
        )
    }

}

const EventVieverHeader = () => (
    <tr>
        <td>{event.title}</td>
        <td>{event.startDate}</td>
        <td>{event.userList.length}</td>
        <td><Badge color="success">Coming</Badge></td>
    </tr>
);


const EventVieverBody = ({events}) => (
    <tbody>
        {events.map(
            event => {
                <tr>
                    <td>{event.title}</td>
                    <td>{event.startDate}</td>
                    <td>{event.userList.length}</td>
                    <td><Badge color="success">Coming</Badge></td>
                </tr> 
        })}
     </tbody>
    )
```